# Swift warning message not clear

Tags: swift, warnings

Can You explain to me what this warning message means?

```
let x = cell.backgroundView!.layer.sublayers as! [CALayer]
```

> Forced cast from '[CALayer]?' to '[CALayer]' only unwraps optionals;  did you mean to use '!'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a forced cast makes no sense. `sublayers` returns an optional array. You should safely unwrap the optional array.

```
if let sublayers = cell.backgroundView?.layer.sublayers {
    // do something with sublayers (which is a non-optional [CALayer])
}
```

Also notice the use of `?` after `backgroundView` instead of `!`.

Please spend time learning how to properly use optionals by reading the [relevant sections](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) in the Swift book. Otherwise your app is going to crash. See [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu) for lot of details about that outcome.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. When I adopt your suggestion I get a (strange ?) error in the second command - let x = cell.backgroundView!.layer.sublayers             let _ = x.map({$0.removeFromSuperlayer()})   which is flagged as error Value of type '[CALayer]' has no member 'removeFromSuperlayer'

Comment: Now you are asking about an entirely different question. If this answer solved your original question about the cast, then indicate this by accepting this answer. Then post a new question about your new issue with all relevant code and error messages

Comment: I accepted the answer ( by clicking the up arrow?) . The second issue was my original issue which I solved by the cast (as!) but still encountered the warning. Thank you for the effort in solving my issues. David

Comment: You accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer (just below the votes).